# How to fetch the array record?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I fetch an array from API using

```
<?php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("API_URL"), TRUE);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($json);
?>
```

I got that result like that

```
    Array
    (
        [deals] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [activeDa

te] => 1430332361000
                    [bogo] => 
                    [categories] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 29057
                                    [name] => Bath & Body
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 20733
                                    [name] => Cosmetics
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 29190
                                    [name] => Skin Care
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 20856
                                    [name] => Fragrances
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 29059
                                    [name] => Beauty & Personal Care
                                )

                        )

                    [clearance] => 
                    [couponCode] => HAPPYMOM
                    [dealImageUrl] => http://cdn.savings.com/logo/1737578.png
                    [dealUrl] => http://www.savings.com/m/p/19561077/8306099/c?afsrc=1&up=2015-05-01-05-15
                    [description] => Go through this link to get Assorted Spring Getaway tote for only $20 on orders $40 or more, save 80%. Restrictions may apply. Limited time offer only or when supplies run out.
                    [discount] => 1
                    [exclusive] => 
                    [freeShipping] => 
                    [homePageStaffPick] => 
                    [id] => 3862713
                    [lastUpdated] => 1430332361000
                    [merchantDisplayUrl] => http://www.bathandbodyworks.com
                    [merchantId] => 236514
                    [merchantImageUrl] => http://cdn.savings.com/logo/1737578.png
                    [merchantName] => Bath and Body Works
                    [merchantPageStaffPick] => 
                    [merchantScore] => 17
                    [merchantUrl] => http://www.savings.com/m/p/19561077/1742990/c?afsrc=1
                    [minimumSpend] => 0.00
                    [mobileMonetized] => 
                    [monetized] => 1
                    [printable] => 
                    [promotion] => 80% Off
                    [rebate] => 
                    [scope] => SITE_WIDE
                    [score] => 579
                    [siteUrls] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => http://www.bathandbodyworks.com
                        )

                    [startDate] => 1430290800000
                    [tip] => 
                    [title] => Get 80% off Assorted Spring Getaway Tote on Orders Over $40 - Only $20
                    [validated] => 
                    [voteDown] => 0
                    [voteUp] => 0
                )
```

My question is how i  get the value of `[deals][categories][0][name]` ?
I want to store value of categories name.

Comment: [deals][0][categories][0][name] try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your answer in your question itelf. just a little modifiction needed. Please try this:-

```
echo $yourarrayname['deals'][0]['categories'][0]['name'];
```

Note:-since category is on the Zero th index of deals. So put zero index before category index.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Good to hear that it solves your problem.:)

Answer (score 1):

You already have your answer. The only thing you need to do is make them literal strings and take the first element in the deals array. So:

```
echo $json['deals'][0]['categories'][0]['name']
```